# OpenCV - merge function Exception at memory location

Tags: c++, opencv, merge, split

I am trying to merge single-channel images into one multiple-channel image. But it shows an error at the merge function:

> cv::Exception at memory location

**code:**

```c
#include <vector>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main() {
    Mat input = imread("a jpeg image");
    Mat B, G, R, merged;
    vector<Mat> channels(3), channels2(3);

    //-- split
    split(input, channels);
    B = channels[0];
    G = channels[1];
    R = channels[2];

    //-- merge
    channels2.push_back(B);
    channels2.push_back(G);
    channels2.push_back(R);

    merge(channels2, merged);
    imshow("merged", merged);

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

I am using Visual Studio on Windows.
How can I fix this?

P.S. My final goal is to merge 4 images (i.e., Blue, Green, Hue, and Gray-scale) into a 4-channel and use it as input for the `mean` function. Would this work with Mat object? Or the 3rd channel has to be Red, 4th channel has to be alpha?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare a couple of vectors of `3` elements (`size`) each, but do not initialize their values:

```
vector<Mat> channels(3), channels2(3);
```

What's the initial value of these first `3` elements?

After this, you `push_back` another `3` elements into the same vector:

```
channels2.push_back(B);
channels2.push_back(G);
channels2.push_back(R);
```

So, `channels2` has now `6` elements. And here's the question: Are all these elements of same `data type` and `size`? They must be if you want to merge them together! If you want to merge just the `BGR` channels, you can do this instead:

```
std::vector<cv::Mat> channels2; //Notice I declared an empty vector

//Push the individual channels into the vector:
channels2.push_back(B);
channels2.push_back(G);
channels2.push_back(R);

//Merge the channels
cv::Mat outputMat;
cv::merge( channels2, outputMat);
```

Of course, if you declare the vector with an initial capacity (`size`) and initial values, you can index each element using `std::vector<>::operator[]` instead of using `push_back`. Either use one method but do not mix them up.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The vector should have been empty.

Comment: @HadiGhahremanNezhad No problem, man! We all miss little things, happy coding!